# Python MySql Connector Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Can't Insert Values into MySql Database Using This Piece Of Code:

```
def CreateUser(Name, Password, Email, Version):
    global user
    print(Password)
    user = [tuple(Name), tuple(Email), tuple(Password), tuple("User"), tuple("0"), tuple(Version)]
    my_cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO users (usersUid, usersEmail, usersPwd, UsersPerms, usersMoney, gameVersion) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", user)
    database.commit()
```

Tried to Insert Values/Data to MySql Database Using Function and Succesfully Inserting it without problems when Code was a little bit edited it worked on MySql Workbench, every value should be correct and there's needed amount of it 6 are data I need and theres 7 in WorkBench Display but thats Id So I skipped that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def CreateUser(Name, Password, Email, Version):
    global user
    print(Password)
    user = [(Name, Email, Password, "User", "0", Version)]
    my_cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO users (usersUid, usersEmail, usersPwd, UsersPerms, usersMoney, gameVersion) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", user)
    database.commit()
```